# Kubuntu - Strange Copy-Paste behaviour after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: clipboard, kubuntu, highlighting

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 with Kubuntu. I had to delete Python2 to do it, but it worked.

However, since the update, something strange is occuring with the copy paste function. A piece of copied text can be pasted into an empty place; however, if the text is being pasted in replacement of other text, however, it instead copies the text being highlighted!

For example, say I copy `hello`. If I paste it into an empty text field, I get `hello`. However, if I copy `world`, then highlight `hello` and try to paste it there, it will instead copy the text `hello` instead, meaning that every paste after that will just be `hello`!

What could be causing this strange behaviour? The keyboard shortcuts look correct...

Comment: It almost looks like something is synchronizing your primary selection and the clipboard, and by highlighting `hello` it automatically copies it into the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in clipboard settings - by default it was set to copy any text that was selected. I disabled this by right clicking on the clipboard and setting `Ignore Selection`.